# Save list of items - js angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have a page code like below. There is a list of items. How can I get the value of Test, Application, Success, Error from the following items? Please help. I am trying to write this data to a file, but it gets [object, Object]

```
 <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="grid-container">
  <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="grid-x">
    <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="small-12 medium-12 large-6 cell">Test:</div>
    <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="small-12 medium-12 large-6 cell">
      <!--bindings={
"ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span _ngcontent-c5="" class="success">It works</span>
      <!--bindings={
"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
      <!--bindings={
"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="grid-x">
    <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="small-12 medium-12 large-6 cell">Application:</div>
    <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="small-12 medium-12 large-6 cell">
      <!--bindings={
"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
      <!--bindings={
"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
      <!--bindings={
"ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><span _ngcontent-c5="" class="error">Error</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My code:

```
it('save to file', () => {
var fs = require('fs');

var area = element.all(by.css('.div.grid-container'));
var outputFileName = 'Output.json';
fs.writeFile(outputFileName, area, function(err){
if(err){
  console.log(err);
}
else{
  console.log("JSON saved to " + outputFileName);
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `JSON.stringify(area)` to convert the object to a JSON string before attempting to save it to a file.